# Sum of the series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone help me with the following sum?

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}$$

I begin as

$$\sum \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...$$

Now, $$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...= \ln 2$$

So, $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...=1-\ln 2$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great, thanks!!